# How to install codelldb cli on Apple Silicon

Tags: c, debugging, rust, vscode-debugger, helix-editor

I want to be able to debug C and Rust Code in the Helix Editor. According to its documentation, I need the lldb of VSCode, codelldb.

Any other DAP that works is fine for me.

I am using a MacBook Pro 2022 with the M2 Processor (arm64)

[vscode-lldb GitHub Repository](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb)

[CodeLLDB VSCode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb)

Couldn't find it on homebrew or macports.

I tried to build the v1.8.1 tag from source but got compile errors.

I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[github release](https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/releases/download/v1.9.0/codelldb-aarch64-darwin.vsix)
just extract the file as zip and find the executable binary in there: /extension/adapter/*

place is somewhere in the path so helix could find it

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install llvm

ln -s $(brew --prefix)/opt/llvm/bin/lldb-vscode $(brew --prefix)/bin/
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?